# Run a build configuration in Teamcity using the Rest API

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I used to use Jenkins for CI and could trigger a job via the REST api.

I'm currently using TeamCity 8 and want to try and do the same thing...

I can find the build configuration I want using

`http://teamcity.url/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:MyInterestingJob`

Is it possible to run that Build configuration?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only since version 8.1 and up

You need to send a POST to the http://teamcity.url/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue endpoint with the build node as the content.

e.g. POST this XML

```
<build>
    <buildType id="MyInterestingJob"/>
</build>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I did see that reference earlier but how do I post my patch file?